# $\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^3}(r^2+\vec r \cdot \vec c)\delta(\vec r -\vec c)d\tau=2|\vec c|^2$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, dirac-delta

Let $\vec c$ be a constant vector:

$$\int \limits_{\mathbb{R}^3}(r^2+\vec r \cdot \vec c)\delta(\vec r -\vec c)d\tau \\=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(r^2+\vec r \cdot \vec c)\delta(x -c_x)\delta( y - c_y)\delta( z -c_z)dzdydx \\ 
=\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int \limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x^2+y^2+z^2+xc_x+yc_y+zc_z)\delta(x -c_x)\delta( y - c_y)\delta( z -c_z)dzdydx\\
= c_x^2+c_y^2+c_z^2+c_x^2+c_y^2+c_z^2=  2\cdot(c_x^2+c_y^2+c_z^2)=2|\vec c|^2$$

Do you disagree with any step that I took in my calculation?

Comment: Can't you leave out all the coordinate stuff and see it directly from the beginning? What is $\int_{\Bbb R^3} f(\vec r)\delta(\vec r) d\vec r$?